# Select multiple options from suggestion in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a chatbot using dialogflow and I want that a user will be able to select multiple responses from Suggestions.

Is there any way to get it done using dialogflow fulfillment or something else? Or is there some other alternative to implement this?

Comment: You didn't specify what channel are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and my finding is that we can't select multiple suggestion chips.
but if you want to select multiple items from user in single intent then you can use ***"IS LIST"*** option in actions and parameters.

suppose you have an entity ***"fruits"*** having values ***{apple, orange, mango etc}***

bot: what would you like to eat

user: I would like to have apple and mango

for this add training phrase ***"I would like to have apple and orange"***

and in actions and parameters select ***"IS LIST"*** against ***"fruits"*** entity

Answer (score 1):

[Suggestion Chips](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#suggestion_chips) are meant to be hints or ways to pivot the conversation.

Depending on your use case you can guide your user through different options. For example, if they are selecting a shirt, you can first ask for the color and then the size -- separating the different options to smaller subsets. A different option/example is for selecting music style (where one can choose one or several options) can be ask them to tell you the style of music they like (while providing 5 suggestion chips) and then in your response you confirm the styles and allow them to add more (while providing 4 suggestion chips of music styles and another that says "All done") --- I think I would also use this design to implement ranking of their preferred music.